# Solr dynamic schema updation using solrj

Tags: solr, solrj

- I am a new to solr working on solr version 4.8.0. I want to add/update/delete fields in the schema.xml at runtime using solrj. i can create or delete a core using solrj.
- For adding documents or search using solrj, i referred [this link](http://www.solrtutorial.com/solrj-tutorial.html)
- I want to learn advance functionality in [solrj](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj). I need any good tutorials or example code.
  Can anyone please guide me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 3rd question is not clear to me, could you explain it?

Comment: Hi @Kumar, have you found a way to add a field to the shema with Solrj?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this page - https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaRESTAPI contains all you need. Pay attention to **Modifying the schema** section. Although, it's not SolrJ way but it will work fine for you.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Can't i use those functions using solrj?

Comment: Take a look here - all you have in Server class is about docs, not about schema - http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_10_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrServer.html. As far as I understand Solr community doesn't think of using SolrJ instead of RestAPI features.

Answer (score 2):

Solrj version 5.3 ([features](http://yonik.com/solr-5-3/)) introduced an experimental [Schema API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_3_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/request/schema/SchemaRequest.html).